# How to fix file tabs position in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, tabs

If lots of files opened in notepad++, there will be several lines of file tabs.

Click on different file tabs will change tab position. Is there a way to fix  tab position? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this? - http://superuser.com/questions/153109/is-there-a-way-to-manage-tabs-efficiently-in-notepad?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link. It could be a direct way to select file if we can fix tab position.

Comment: Disable multi-line tab might be the only option.